# Creating individual spaced columns in tables

Tags: tables, width

I'm just getting started with Latex and used several ressouces to create my first document. I'm making progress but I'm struggling with a table.

I have 7 rows, the bottom two are supposed to look like in the screenshot, with individual widths so that the two words fit unhyphenated. But in order to achieve that, I had to basically create 3 tables and there's a little gap now that doesn't look very nice. Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm going for in one single table and thus get rid of the gap?

EDIT: edited code to be compileable. My goal is to make **only one** table, but with the same outcome as it is now.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\newcolumntype{~}{!{\hrule width 1pt}}
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\title{Übung}
\author{Phil}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\section{Tabelle}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{? p{2cm} | p{6cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
Instrumente & Funktionsweise & Beispiele & Vorteile & Nachteile \\
\hline

Information und Aufklärung \newline Appell &  über Notwendigkeit von 
Maßnahmen aufklären und entsprechende Handlungen motivieren & 
Energiekennzeichnung \newline dena-Mobilität Kampagne & u.U. günstig 
Mobilisierung von eigenverantwortlichem Handeln & Erfolg nicht kalkulierbar 
und im Allg. zu gering \\ \hline

Vor"-bild"-funk"-tion & staatliche Behörden gehen in ihrem eigenen Bereich 
mit gutem Beispiel voran & energieeffizientere Neubauten des Bundes & Erfolg 
im "Kleinen" kann sichergestellt werden \newline Stärkung der Glaubwürdigkeit 
& Wirkung über den staatlichen Bereich hinaus nicht kalkulierbar \\ \hline

finanzielle Anreize \newline steuerlicher Anreiz, Subventionen, günstige 
Kredite & Überwindung von Handlungsbarrieren der Akteure durch ansonsten 
nicht ausreichende Wirtschaftlichekit oder zu hohe Investitionskosten & 
Förderung der Elektromobilität \newline kfw-Kredite & starke Unterstützung 
des eigenverantwortlichen Handelns & schwierige Dimensionierung nicht zu viel 
hinen stecken, aber auch nicht so wenig, dass der Effekt verlorengeht \\ 
\hline

Selbst"-ver"-pflichtung & Organisatorische Organisationen verppflichten sich 
selbst zu Klimaschutzzielen & Selbstverpflichtung der deutschen Industrie &             
keine Gesetze erforderlich \newline Effizienz der Maßnahme ist wahrscheinlich 
& keine sehr große Verbindlichkeit \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{? p{3cm} | p{5cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}

\textlcsc{Emissionssteuer} & Besteuerung der Emissionen von Treibhausgasen & 
Steuern in Schweden oder in British Columbia, Canada & Effizienz gegeben 
\newline Effekt wird erzielt & Höhe des Effekts ist unklar \ u.U. Abwanderung 
von Unternehmen \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{? p{4.1cm} | p{3.9cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}
\textlcsc{Emissions|rechte|handel} \newline \textlcsc{Emissionshandel} &  Die 
Ausgabe von handelbaren Emissionsrechten & EU-Emissionshandel & Effizienz und 
Zielerreichung sind gegeben & Abwanderung, Bürokratie, \newline nicht 
perfektes System \\ 
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of the pdf, the | in the last word are there on purpose:
[image: gaps in table that are probably not optimal]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: please complete your example so people can run it (eg `?` is a syntax error by default you have presumably defined it to be a table preamble specification)

Comment: I edited the question.  Basically I want to have the bottom two columns be a different width than the other ones. ? is used to make the outer lines bold

Comment: Your existing solution is pretty good.  I would add `\lineskip=0pt` inside the center environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\lineskip` is the minimum vertical distance added between boxes.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\newcolumntype{~}{!{\hrule width 1pt}}
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\title{Übung}
\author{Phil}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\section{Tabelle}
\begin{center}
\lineskip=0pt %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% One Line Patch
\begin{tabular}{? p{2cm} | p{6cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
Instrumente & Funktionsweise & Beispiele & Vorteile & Nachteile \\
\hline

Information und Aufklärung \newline Appell &  über Notwendigkeit von 
Maßnahmen aufklären und entsprechende Handlungen motivieren & 
Energiekennzeichnung \newline dena-Mobilität Kampagne & u.U. günstig 
Mobilisierung von eigenverantwortlichem Handeln & Erfolg nicht kalkulierbar 
und im Allg. zu gering \\ \hline

Vor"-bild"-funk"-tion & staatliche Behörden gehen in ihrem eigenen Bereich 
mit gutem Beispiel voran & energieeffizientere Neubauten des Bundes & Erfolg 
im "Kleinen" kann sichergestellt werden \newline Stärkung der Glaubwürdigkeit 
& Wirkung über den staatlichen Bereich hinaus nicht kalkulierbar \\ \hline

finanzielle Anreize \newline steuerlicher Anreiz, Subventionen, günstige 
Kredite & Überwindung von Handlungsbarrieren der Akteure durch ansonsten 
nicht ausreichende Wirtschaftlichekit oder zu hohe Investitionskosten & 
Förderung der Elektromobilität \newline kfw-Kredite & starke Unterstützung 
des eigenverantwortlichen Handelns & schwierige Dimensionierung nicht zu viel 
hinen stecken, aber auch nicht so wenig, dass der Effekt verlorengeht \\ 
\hline

Selbst"-ver"-pflichtung & Organisatorische Organisationen verppflichten sich 
selbst zu Klimaschutzzielen & Selbstverpflichtung der deutschen Industrie &             
keine Gesetze erforderlich \newline Effizienz der Maßnahme ist wahrscheinlich 
& keine sehr große Verbindlichkeit \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{? p{3cm} | p{5cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}

\textlcsc{Emissionssteuer} & Besteuerung der Emissionen von Treibhausgasen & 
Steuern in Schweden oder in British Columbia, Canada & Effizienz gegeben 
\newline Effekt wird erzielt & Höhe des Effekts ist unklar \ u.U. Abwanderung 
von Unternehmen \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{? p{4.1cm} | p{3.9cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} ?}
\textlcsc{Emissions|rechte|handel} \newline \textlcsc{Emissionshandel} &  Die 
Ausgabe von handelbaren Emissionsrechten & EU-Emissionshandel & Effizienz und 
Zielerreichung sind gegeben & Abwanderung, Bürokratie, \newline nicht 
perfektes System \\ 
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```